# Cargar datos de excel en R sin modificar el formato

Tags: r

Espero puedan ayudarme con la siguiente consulta, es mi primera pregunta 
He revisado todas las preguntas similares y nada que encuentro una opción

Uso la librería read_excel para cargar mis archivos de Excel en R y por primera vez me enfrento a un problema que no he podido solucionar (también uso readxl y xlsx).

Algunos de los valores están en Excel con formato de porcentaje (99.8% 55%) y al leer el archivo esos valores pasan a número (0.998 0.55)
Usando la opción col_types no ayuda tampoco

La columna tiene diferentes tipos de datos, por la naturaleza de la información, entonces no es una opción simplemente multiplicar por 100 ya que aparte de esos porcentajes también tengo cantidades enteras.

Le agradezco si alguien se ha encontrado con este problema me cuente cómo lo pudo solucionar.

Gracias!!!

**EDITADO**

No puedo poner parte de los datos, pero aquí un ejemplo para que sea más claro.
La primera imagen muestra los datos del excel, algunos en % y otros números enteros, no es posible obtener los datos de otra manera.
La segunda imagen es al cargar el Excel en R.
Estoy buscando alguna opción que me permita leer ese dato de Excel tal cual está en el archivo.
Gracias por sus respuestas

[image: Datos Excel]

[image: Datos R]

```
>  area    Colombia Chile  Peru
   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>

1  opcion1   0.99  1    12   
2  opcion2   1     NA   NA   
3  opcion3   15    0.45 NA   
4  opcion4   0.953 10   NA   
5  opcion5   26    NA   0.1
6  opcion6   NA    3    0.26
7  opcion7   NA    NA   0.55
```

Una muestra de cómo son leídos los datos en R:

```
> dput(datos)

structure(list(area = c("opcion1", "opcion2", "opcion3", "opcion4", 
"opcion5", "opcion6", "opcion7"), Colombia = c(0.99, 1, 15, 0.953, 
26, NA, NA), Chile = c(1, NA, 0.45, 10, NA, 3, NA), Peru = c(12, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.1, 0.26, 0.55)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(area = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Colombia = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Chile = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Peru = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"),
class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hola @Janneth Sánchez! Tendrás mayor posibilidad de ter una buena respuesta si incluyes un ejemplo mínimamente reproducible de tu problema. Para eso, puedes incluir el código que usas, una muestra de tus datos (usa `dput(head(data))`) en R para eso) y cuál es específicamente la manera como deseas que la variable sea codificada en R. Este link puede darte ideas sobre cómo crear el ejemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: La columna en cuestión tiene datos codificados en diferentes clases? Si es así, dale una mirada al concepto de "Tidy data": https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf y considera si es necesario y posible, por ejemplo,  crear una lista para separar las variables o simplemente dividir esa columna según el tipo de dato.

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios, he editado la pregunta. Saludos!!

Comment: ¿Y que quisieras hacer  con los datos que no representan un porcentaje?

Comment: Hola, Los debo dejar tal cual como están, esos están bien

Answer (score 0):

Primero algo que no deberíamos olvidar "la representación de un dato no es el dato", en este caso la columna que muestras tiene solo valores numéricos, que se muestra de forma distinta por que se ha aplicado un formato, pero `95.30 %` es un representación, el dato es `0.9530`, por eso no sirve tratar la columna con `col_types="text"`, la columna se leerá como texto, pero se verá como `"0.9530"`. El problema que deberías solucionar es anterior al que estás planteando, la columna debería estar normalizada, en todo caso una para los porcentajes y otra para el resto de los valores.

Pero, ¿se puede hacer algo?, si, pero cualquier solución va a ser del tipo "rascarse el oído izquierdo con el pie derecho", o sea estrambótica, antinatural, complicada y seguramente imperfecta.

Lo que se me ocurre, siempre que el patrón sea: los números inferiores a 1 representan un porcentaje y los otros simplemente un número, reconstruir en un `character` el formato que viene del Excel:

```
df$Colombia_chr <- ifelse(df$Colombia < 1, paste0(df$Colombia * 100, "%"), df$Colombia)
```

Otra opción, que conceptualmente es idéntica al código anterior, pero eventualmente podría ser más precisa, sería identificar que celdas tienen el formato de porcentaje, para de esta forma aplicar sobre el dato, el formato apropiado y transformarlo en una cadena. Para esto no sirve `readxl` por que solo obtienes los datos, pero podrías usar `tidyxl` que te permite obtener una visón completa de datos y atributos de una archivo entero en un único `data.frame`. Por ejemplo para obtener el formato usado en la hoja 1 y columna 1:

```
library(tidyxl)

x <- xlsx_cells(file)
subset(x, sheet == 'Hoja1' & col == 1)['local_format_id']
```

Teniendo el formato ya podrías saber con más precisión en que celdas deberías "reformatear" el valor para representar el porcentaje

PD: por cierto, también te podrías tomar el trabajo de editar la columna en el Excel e ir agregándole un tilde sencillo a los datos con porcentaje para convertir el valor en una cadena, pero ciertamente el trabajo tal vez sea demasiado largo.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Modificar el excel no es una opción porque es una fuente de datos global, varios países obtienen el archivo de esta manera y el proceso se debe automatizar por lo que yo no voy a tocar los archivos. La condición de menor que uno ya lo había pensado pero no sirve porque no puedo diferenciar el 100% del 1... Y pues no puedo saber cuántas filas o columnas va a traer el archivo porque depende del mes... Estoy buscando una columna adicional que me permita condicionar cuáles datos multiplicar por 100. Gracias fe todas maneras por tu tiempo

Comment: Janeth, hay cosas que no se pueden y/o no se deben hacer, a veces es mejor decir NO que intentar soluciones complicadas y potencialmente ineficaces. De todas formas te sugerí en mi respuestas que uses tidyxl para determinar en que celdas se está usando el formato que corresponde al porcentaje y aplicar la multiplicación por 100 solo a estas celdas, eso debería funcionar.

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios. Saludos!!!